# Slackbot responds with username

Tags: slack

Is it possible to have Slackbot (or a custom bot) incorporate, in its response, the name of the user that asked it something?

For example something like:

> "This is a message for `/invoking_user`: blabla."

Resulting in:

> "This is a message for Dave: blabla."

I have looked around the web and sought some information on custom bots, but haven't found the answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a built in slack command that will do this.  However, you can make your own custom slack commands.  Here is a link to some documentation.

https://my.slack.com/services/new/slash-commands

Also, for a more complete answer.  Here is a list of the built in slack commands.

https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201259356-Using-slash-commands

Hope that helps!